# Equivalent of Substring as a RegularExpression

Tags: c#, regex

Ok, I need a general regular expression that will give me the x characters from a string starting at position y like the string's substring function:

input_str.Substring(y,x)

But as a C# regular expression.

Example:
1234567890   Substring(5,3)   678

I know you are thinking why not just use the Substring function?  The short answer is because this goes as a data for an existing function and in this context it would be inelegant to create a whole separate data parsing mechanism.  We'd like to get this working without changing the code.

I feel like this is really obvious--but I'm pretty inexperienced with regular expressions.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.{y}(.{x}).*` should do it, I think, then just pull out the capture group.