# Regex Substring or Left Equivalent

Tags: c#, regex

Greetings beloved comrades.

I cannot figure out how to accomplish the following via a regex.

I need to take this format number `201101234` and transform it to `11-0123401`, where digits 3 and 4 become the digits to the left of the dash, and the remaining five digits are inserted to the right of the dash, followed by a hardcoded 01.

I've tried http://gskinner.com/RegExr, but the syntax just defeats me.

This answer, [Equivalent of Substring as a RegularExpression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675775/equivalent-of-substring-as-a-regularexpression), sounds promising, but I can't get it to parse correctly.

I can create a SQL function to accomplish this, but I'd rather not hammer my server in order to reformat some strings.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really want regex? A substring would be enough.

Comment: Probably.  The interface I'm using supports regex, custom C#/VB scripts (I'm nothing but a SQL reports developer), and custom SQL queries. Which is my last resort is to do it with a SQL query.  The software is Laserfiche Workflow Designer, btw.

Comment: If you can use custom C# scripts, just use number.Substring(2,2) + number.Substring(4) + "01"

Comment: "Greetings beloved comrades" best greeting I've seen here yet.

Comment: @JefferyKhan Not to mention the fact that 'Projectile Leprosy' sounds like perhaps the most terrifying disease in the world. :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var input = "201101234";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"^\d{2}(\d{2})(\d{5})$", "${1}-${2}01");

Console.WriteLine(output); // 11-0123401
```

This will match:

- two digits, followed by
- two digits captured as group 1, followed by
- five digits captured as group 2

And return a string which replaces that matched text with

- group 1, followed by
- a literal hyphen, followed by
- group 2, followed by
- a literal `01`.

The start and end anchors ( `^` / `$` ) ensure that if the input string does not *exactly* match this pattern, it will simply return the original string.

Comment: You can explain your regex so that it will be helpful for others

Comment: MATCHER: Matches two digits (\d matches a digit), captures the following two digits, captures the following five digits. REPLACER: Uses the captured groups in output to build the new format.

Comment: I receive an excellent error:  The name 'Regex' does not exist in the current context.  I'm trying the C# script option.

Comment: @Projectile_Leprosy declare a using directive `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` or just use `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` instead of `Regex`

Comment: @Projectile_Leprosy Make sure you add `using System.Text.RegularExpressions` to the top of your file, or use the full class name `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(...)`

Answer (score 8):

If you can use custom C# scripts, you may want to use Substring instead:

```
string newStr = string.Format("{0}-{1}01", old.Substring(2,2), old.Substring(4));
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you really need a regex here. Substring would be better. But still if you want regex only, you can use this:

```
string newString = Regex.Replace(input, @"^\d{2}(\d{2})(\d+)$", "$1-${2}01");
```

Explanation:

```
^\d{2}    // Match first 2 digits. Will be ignored
 (\d{2})  // Match next 2 digits. Capture it in group 1
 (\d+)$   // Match rest of the digits. Capture it in group 2
```

Now, the required digits, are in group 1 and 2, which you use in the replacement string.

Comment: That will actually output `"11-$201"`

Answer (score 0):

Do you even SQL?  Pull some levers and stuff.

Comment: Climbed out of the 1 rep basement, have you?  How many men did that take?

Comment: I don't know what that has to do with anything! Stay on the original topic.

Comment: Take that!  I'll inflate your rep to lure others into believing you.